# Disable the "selected" property of a DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes

Tags: c#, devexpress, treelist

I am using the `DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes` control, after a node of this type is appended to a `DevExpress.XtraTreeList` object by

```
TreeList1.AppendNode(new object[] {"hello word"}, -1);
```

I don't want this node to be selected, i.e., disable the `selected` property. How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

By default, one node in the TreeList control is always focused. This node is specified by the [FocusedNode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FocusedNodetopic) property. If you do not want any node to have focus, set the FocusedNode property to null:

```
treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "hello word" }, -1);
treeList1.FocusedNode = null;
```